# Pausing an amp-animation at a specific time

Tags: amp-html

Is it currently possible to pause a amp-animation at a specific time?

Sample scenario:

1. I have an animation (10s) that starts with an intro (2s).
2. I want the animation to pause at 2s.
3. The user can click on a button to resume the playback of that animation.

Point 1 and 3 is already working. But I am not sure how to implement point 2, If it is even possible.
Any help/hint highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please share you code.

Comment: thanks. I don't think that code is necessary here. I just want to know if it is generally possible to stop an animation at a specific time WITHOUT user interaction (e.g. click)

Comment: If you check the [timing properties in amp documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation#timing-properties), it think that's what you are looking for if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use two `amp-animations` since there is no `timer` in AMP to pause the animation at 2s. Have first be the intro and autoplay and second to be triggered by user action.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the solution I came up with. A simple timeline trigger that could be used within an animation would be a great feature request though.